# datagridview value already exist vb

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

this is my code for checking if a value(from dgvlist) already exist in dgvorders, my problem is the error message only shows for the first selectedrow of the dgvlist and the rest still adds.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvOrders.Rows
        For i = 0 To dgvOrders.Rows.Count - 1
            If row.Cells(0).Value = dgvList.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value Then
                MsgBox("item already listed!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Else : dgvOrders.Rows.Add(v, w, x, y, z)

            End If
            Exit Sub
            Exit For
        Next 
    Next
```

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you are doing, but I'm pretty sure you don't want to nest a loop of dgvOrders within a loop of dgvOrders. You are looping over that grid (number of rows) squared times.

Comment: Your code doesn't have 1 problem, but quite a few of them. I seriously doubt that any person making even the slightest effort could deliver 10 lines of VB.NET code including so many errors.

Comment: oops, typo error..

its not i=0 to dgvorders.rows.count but dgvlist instead

Comment: @varocarbas if you can't help then just ignore my post and don't comment. im new to this thing that's why im asking for help .

Comment: I am helping you understand that you shouldn't be doing what you are doing. Firstly, this is not the way to learn; and secondly, this is not the way to use SO. Helping others does not necessarily imply to give them exactly what they want, but what they need.

Comment: @varocarbas, sir that's the reason why i post my code.. to be corrected if your telling me that i shouldn't do it then what's the purpose of this site?

Comment: You posted this code because you are new (in this site and in programming, at least with VB.NET) and you made a mistake. What you should do is learning by your own (from a book, online resources, a course... whatever), by doing as much research (including the already asked/answered SO posts) and testing as possible. Once you have got a proper understanding, if you find a very specific issue which you cannot solve (even after the research) and which might also be helpful to others, you could come ask here...

Comment: .. SO is not for basic-learning, but for solving very specific problems of knowledgeable-enough programmers. For learning you have others sites and alternatives (although I do recommend you to do most of the effort by your own). Let me put it other way: would you go to a website for expert mathematicians and ask about what is the meaning of "+"? What would the people there answer you in that situation? You are basically doing the same, but additionally without providing the required information (e.g., like going to the aforementioned site, but just saying that it is a "weird symbol").

Comment: @varocarbas ok sir thanks for your opinion but like what i've said you can just ignore my post anyway its not posted intended for you.

Answer (score 0):

Because after If statement you are using End sub so once the first record is compared, It is coming out of entire sub.

Comment: i tried removing the exit sub but  result to another error

Comment: sorry,no error but when i remove the exit for it adds nothing but the datagrid scroll gets smaller. sorry for my grammar

Comment: are blank rows getting added ? use insert break point feature while run. see what exactly happening. you may get a idea.

Comment: no, when i select a blank row it gets the value of the last row.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you focus on each item in turn. You only want one `For Each ... Next` loop (unless you also wanted to traverse the columns).

Next get the value to test into a variable `ValueFromdgvList`. It should be declared as a number or string to match the value expected. I don't know if I have the right syntax or the right value in the code below. You should put a breakpoint in your code and step it so you can check that you have the expected value before starting your compare.

Finally to add a row you need to set the values to an array. Better would be to define a new DataGridViewRow and add the values to that. Finally add it to the DataGridView. But I'll leave that.

```
    'change this as needed
    Dim ValueFromdgvList As String = dgvList.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
    Debug.Print(ValueFromdgvList)

    Dim haveMatch As Boolean
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvOrders.Rows
        If row.Cells(0).Value = ValueFromdgvList Then
            haveMatch = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If haveMatch Then
        MsgBox("item already listed!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    Else
        Dim ValuesArray() As Object = {v, w, x, y, z}
        dgvOrders.Rows.Add(ValuesArray)
    End If
```

We're using `haveMatch` because we don't want to add a new row until we've checked all the rows.

Comment: thank you for your answer sir but i already found the error. its the exit sub.

Comment: So if Exit Sub was the problem you should accept Bharath R answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left. Or if this answer was better you should accept this one. You can also upvote either or both answers.